# How to reliably measure time of sess.run() in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, caching, tensorflow, profiling, timeit

My problem is that if the arguments of an operation are constant, TF caches the results:

```
a = tf.constant(np.random.randn(*(100, 101)))
b = tf.constant(np.random.randn(*(100, 102)))
c = tf.constant(np.random.randn(*(101, 102)))
# Some expensive operation.
res = tf.einsum('si,sj,ij->s', a, b, c)
%timeit sess.run(res)
```

> The slowest run took 577.76 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   10000 loops, best of 3: 137 µs per loop

If I'm generating the tensors from scratch on each run, then I'm also counting the overhead on tensor generation:

```
a = tf.random_normal((100, 101))
b = tf.random_normal((100, 102))
c = tf.random_normal((101, 102))
res = tf.einsum('si,sj,ij->s', a, b, c)
%timeit sess.run(res)
```

> The slowest run took 4.07 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
>   10 loops, best of 3: 28 ms per loop

Maybe in this particular example the overhead is not large, but for cheaper operations it can be significant.

Is there any way to freeze the arguments so they will not be recomputed on each sess.run(), but suppress all other caching?

Answer (score 0):

On each run (across sessions), whatever tensor objects that you pass to `sess.run()` will be evaluated. From the docs:

> A Session object encapsulates the environment in which Operation objects are 
>   executed, and Tensor objects are evaluated.

It's not possible to ignore evaluating(computing the values of) the tensors across sessions, as long as it's part of the expression to be evaluated.

In your example, the tensor objects `a, b, c` are always evaluated in each session since the values of them are needed to compute einsum. But, within a session, they're computed only once and cached across runs.

But, within a session, you can make it to get evaluated only once and use it elsewhere. But again this works only within a session.

Comment: So you're saying that there is nothing we can do to reliably measure the execution time of an op such as einsum?  
What if as a dirty hack I fix the arguments, but will multiply them by a random number? It will force TF to recompute everything while not adding a significant overhead...  
    const = tf.random_normal((1,))[0]  
    res = tf.einsum('si,sj,ij->s', const * a, const * b, const * c)

Comment: Within a session, what you're measuring is actually the time taken for the op i.e. `einsum`.

Comment: But it seems like the intermediate computations are cached across the runs, see the first example in the original question. The running time is 137 µs which is much faster than this particular einsum takes on random inputs (even when excluding the time for generating this inputs).

Comment: This might help? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/InteractiveSession#partial_run

Comment: Maybe use placeholders and feed dict?